# collision between an object with physics and another non-physics object in game maker

Tags: physics, collision, game-maker

//sorry for bad English

I'm using Game maker. I enabled physics for world. I have an object and I don't want to get involved with the physics for this object. So I didn't enabled "use Physics". When I set collision Event between this object and another object(qube), the function didn't acts. If I enable "use Physics" this function will be called. So my question is: "how enable collision between an object with physics and another non-physics object in game maker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In object with physics:
(end step)

```
x = phy_position_x
y = phy_position_y
```

In object without physics:
(end step)

```
if collision_rectangle(bbox_left, bbox_top, bbox_right, bbox_bottom, obj_with_physics, false, true) != noone
{
    //collision
}
```

Comment: So I must use function "collision_rectangle" to manually check the collision between object without physics?